# Mysql case statement with numeric values

Tags: mysql

I have table with

```
+------------+-------+-------+
| tran_value | date  | name  |
+------------+-------+-------+
|         10 | 22may | mark  |
|         15 | 23may | mark  |
|         16 | 24may | mark  |
|        300 | 19jun | john  |
|        400 | 20jun | john  |
|        500 | 21jun | john  |
|        600 | 22jun | john  |
|        150 | 12dec | chris |
|        160 | 13dec | chris |
|        170 | 14dec | chris |
|        180 | 15dec | chris |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

and i tried to add outlier in a new column but it is throwing error

```
select date,tran_value,
case name
when name ="mark" and tran_value <=15 then new_trn =NULL
  else tran_value
when name ="john" and tran_value <400 then new_trn =NULL
  else tran_value
when name ="chris" and tran_value <170 then new_trn =NULL
  else tran_value
```

ii.e

```
+------------+-------+-------+
| tran_value | date  | name  |
+------------+-------+-------+
| NULL       | 22may | mark  |
| NULL       | 23may | mark  |
| 16         | 24may | mark  |
| NULL       | 19jun | john  |
| NULL       | 20jun | john  |
| 500        | 21jun | john  |
| 600        | 22jun | john  |
| NULL       | 12dec | chris |
| NULL       | 13dec | chris |
| 170        | 14dec | chris |
| 180        | 15dec | chris |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

any modifications in code....
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date,tran_value,CASE 
        WHEN name ="mark" and tran_value <=15 THEN new_trn =NULL         
        WHEN name ="john" and tran_value <400 THEN new_trn =NULL         
        WHEN name ="chris" and tran_value <170 THEN new_trn =NULL
        ELSE tran_value
END AS new_column;
```

Comment: Remove `name` after `CASE` or alternatively the `name = ` after the `WHEN`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user ,@fancypants